# Problem with printing vector of object pointer backwards?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program to print a vector of object pointers backwards.

My instructions for the part of the lab im stuck on:

> Function main() to use the GroceryItem class above
>
> a. Read a grocery
>   item from standard input (std::cin) until end of file. For each item
>   read:
>
> ```
> i. Store the item in a dynamically allocated object
> ii. Store the pointer to the item in a standard vector
> ```
>
> b. After you have reached the end of file, write the grocery items to standard output (std::cout) in reverse order.
>
> c. Be sure to release the
>   dynamically allocated objects before exiting the program

I tried looking at multiple forums and can't figure out how to print my vector forwards or backwards since it is a pointer to an object. I'm confused on how to print each member within the object

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "GroceryItem.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    // vector of GroceryItem pointer
    std::vector<GroceryItem*> groceries; 

    // variables for the parameter of the constructor
    std::string upc; 
    std::string brand;
    std::string product;
    double price;
    int size;

    std::cout << "How many grocery items are in your list: ", 
    std::cin >> size; // size of vector
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "UPC: ", std::cin >> upc;

        std::cout << "Brand Name: ", std::cin >> brand;

        std::cout << "Product Name: ", std::cin >> product;

        std::cout << "Price: ", std::cin >> price;

        // constructor of GroceryItem object
        groceries.push_back(new GroceryItem(upc, brand, product, price)); 
    }

    // trying to print the vector backwards but it only prints the 
    // address (i want it to print each memeber of the object)
    int iterator = size - 1;
    while (iterator != -1)
    {
        std::cout << groceries[iterator] << "\n";
        iterator--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `std::vector<GroceryItem*>` and not just `std::vector<GroceryItem>`? It makes life a lot easier.

Comment: @NathanOliver such was the task, it is in the problem description.

Comment: Edit the post to highlight the instructions

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `std::vector`. You are stuck on printing a `GroceryItem`. If you simply had a `GroceryItem myItem;` how would you print it?

Comment: What you call an iterator is not actually an iterator. You are using an index. An iterator would actually make this more descriptive as it would change the loop to `for (auto iterator = groceries.rbegin(); iterator != groceries.rend(); ++iterator)`.

Comment: 1) Indenting code properly makes the code readable.  Your post lacks any indentation.  2) *i want it to print each memeber of the object* -- As the previous comment stated, your issue has nothing to do with vector.  If you were to simply attempt to print a `GroceryItem`, vector or no vector, what did you learn so far in your class about overloading `operator <<`?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> //trying to print the vector backwards but it only prints the 
> //address (i want it to print each memeber of the object)
> ```

In that case, use:

```
 std::cout << *(groceries[iterator]) << "\n";
```

However, to be able use that, you must add the following overload:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, GroceryItem const&);
```

Comment: No, OP Is not allowed to do this (use vector of objects)